# How to implement scrolltop of ListView?

Tags: android

I'm building an app Android that have an Activity with a ListView.
So I want to implement a Listener of this ListView that refresh the content of it if the user srollup the ListView, then if the user scroll of the top of the List, it refresh your content.
I'm building this code in my Activity:

```
class OnListListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
        private int currentVisibleItemCount;
        private int currentScrollState;
        private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
        private int totalItem;
        private LinearLayout lBelow;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
            this.isScrollCompleted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            this.totalItem = totalItemCount;
        }

        private void isScrollCompleted() {
            if (currentFirstVisibleItem == 0) {
                //Your loading go here
                Log.i("INFO", "DEVO AGGIORNARE LA LISTA");
                refreshListView();
            }
        }
    }
```

Method onCreate:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble);
            startService(new Intent(this, BlePowerService.class));
            //ISTANZIO LA LISTA IN PAGINA
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnListListener());
            refreshListView();
        }

public void refreshListView() {
        LinkedList<SensorData> listaDati = db.fetchSensorData();
        adapter = new SensorDataAdapter(classe, R.layout.sensordata_row, listaDati);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

If I try to start my app then scroll of the top of the ListView, the interface user is blocket for more second and not works correctly. How can I change it ?

Comment: what is not working correctly?

Comment: because is very Slow the refresh